# Most Efficient way to Get common records from two Arraylist

Tags: arrays, list, collections, hashmap, hashset

I have 2 list

```
ArrayList<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    l1.add("ABCD");

    l1.add("DEF");
    l1.add("GHI");
    l1.add("JKL");
    l1.add("MNO");
    l1.add("PQR");
    l1.add("MNO");

    ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    l2.add("ABC");
    l2.add("DEF");
    l2.add("GHI");
    l2.add("PQR");
    l2.add("STU");
    l2.add("ABC");
```

Data can be in millions as well, i just want to know which will be most efficient way to do the same..

1.Solution-1

public ArrayList getCommonWords(ArrayList list1,
            ArrayList list2)

```
{

    ArrayList<String> commonlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list1.size()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
            if (list1.get(i) == list2.get(j)) {
                commonlist.add(list1.get(i));
                break;
            }

        }
        i++;
    }
    return commonlist;

}
```

Solution 2 - using retain function

Is there any other solution to the same ..like hash etc..if the can be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. You just need to decide which one is more important: speed or memory.

Optimising for speed ( O(N) runtime complexity, O(N) memory complexity):

You would use a hash set for one of your arrays. The expected complexity for find / contains in a HashSet is O(1) and the average depends on the number of buckets (b) which is O(b/N).

```
{
   List <String> common = new ArrayList<>();
   HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
   hs.addAll(l1); // add all the items from l1 to the hashset    
   for (String s : l2) {
     if hs.contains(s) {
       common.add(s);
     }
   }
}
```

If you want to optimise the memory, so you wouldn't have to allocate additional memory you could do it in O(N*M) (assuming l1 and l2 don't have the same size) and O(1) in memory.

```
List <String> common = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : l1) {
  if l2.contains(s) {
    common.add(s);
  }
}
```

This solution you proposed is the same as my second solution.

When comparing objects in java, you shouldn't use `==`. That checks if the object have the same reference. Use instead `equals` which will check if they have the same content.